# Jenkins. Copy a file from multiconfiguration child job's workspace to parent job's workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multiconfiguration job `myjob`. It has a BUILD_TYPES axis with possible values `release` and `debug`. `myjob`is not running on Jenkins master, but on one of the slaves. Since it is a multiconfig job, it is spawning two more builds on slaves (for a total of three slaves working on one `myjob`.) 
`myjob` also triggers a test. The test is triggered with Parameters from file option. This file is written in each configuration (debug and release), and I cannot find a way to copy it from the workspace of the child jobs to the parent job's workspace. I tried Copy to Slave, Copy Artifacts from another project, and some other things to no avail. What is the general approach to copy files from children to parent (all running on different slaves)?